# the datepicker not showing the default text dd/mm/yyyy on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

This is a JSP.
I'm using Bootstrap5 and this is my code :

```
<form action="" method="GET" class="row g-1 mb-3 ">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 mb-2">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate" style="font-size:.9rem">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 mb-2">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" style="font-size:.9rem">
    </div> 
</div>
```

the view on Desktop :

[image]

the view on Mobile

[image]

this is how I import bootstrap :

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
//code
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
```

I have read this answer :
[Date field default text "DD-MM-YYYY" not showing on mobile devices but showing on Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261386/date-field-default-text-dd-mm-yyyy-not-showing-on-mobile-devices-but-showing-o)

but I didn't find it practical.

Remarque : When I test the mobile view with dev tools in the browser it works fine. the problem shows off only when Im on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem in the futur.
Here's how I solved it using CSS and JS.

JS :

```
   const dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');

dateInputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (this.value !== '') {
      this.classList.add('has-value');
    } else {
      this.classList.remove('has-value');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS :

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {

    input[type="date"]::before{
        color: #999;
        content: attr(placeholder);
        margin-right: 3px;

    }
    input[type="date"]:focus::before {
        content: attr(placeholder) !important;

    }
    input[type="date"].has-value:focus::before {
        content: none !important;

    }
    input[type="date"].has-value::before {
        content: none !important;
        
    }

    input[type="date"] {
        display: flex;}

}
```

in HTML just use the attribute placeholder.